# Unable to resolve connection time-out - Hadoop-1.2.1 NameNode & DataNode fail to start; SecondaryNameNode port 22 Connection timed out

Tags: linux, node.js, hadoop, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have been unable to start jsp services on the namenode of a multi-node cluster. I have attempted several solutions that have been suggested in other SO threads for similar (but not identical) problems. However, the namenode jsp services still do not start. Any help in resolving this issue is much appreciated.

I am not an expert, by any stretch, in the complexities of Hadoop and cloud computing (I am, however, an interested but somewhat naive user). I am seeking to better understand those complexities, and appreciate the depth of knowledge that experts in this area possess. To that end, I have been following the Pseudo-Distributed Multi-Node Cluster tutorial as described by Hardik Panday at DZone.Com -

[How to Set Up a Multi-Node Hadoop Cluster on Amazon EC2](https://dzone.com/articles/how-set-multi-node-hadoop)

This tutorial is itself an update of the popular tutorial by Michael Noll, that sets up a single-node cluster [Note A, below] and, later, a multi-node cluster [Note B, below] on AWS EC2. The Panday tutorial, like its predecessor by Noll, is for a 4 node cluster (master, 2nd, 2X slaves); in attempting to stay within the AWS Free Tier limits, I have modified the cluster to be only 3 nodes (master, 2nd and slave).

In following the tutorial, I have encountered no issues, errors, or unexpected warnings until starting hadoop, following the error-free formatting of the namenode:

```
~/home/ubuntu/hadoop/conf$ hadoop start-all.sh

starting namenode, logging to /home/ubuntu/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-<SNN Public DNS>.out  
<Slave Public DNS>: starting datanode, logging to /home/ubuntu/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-<Slave Public DNS>.out  
<SNN Public DNS>: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/ubuntu/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-<SNN Public DNS>.out  
<SNN Public DNS>: ssh: connect to host <NN Public DNS> port 22: Connection timed out  
starting jobtracker,  logging to /home/ubuntu/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu-jobtracker-<SNN Public DNS>.out  
<Slave Public DNS>: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/ubuntu/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu-tasktracker-<Slave Public DNS>.out
```

Checking JPS on the NN, SNN and Slave reveals:

Master is running Jps only
SNN is running SecondaryNameNode and Jps
Slave is running TaskTracker and Jps

NameNode, SecondaryNameNode and JobTracker should be running on the Master
DataNode should be running on the Slave, but is not.

Passwordless ssh has been set-up. The ability to ssh and move files) from the Master to SNN and Slave was confirmed. Each PuTTY session has begun with:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`  
Agent pid XXXXX  
$ ssh-add KeyPairFileName.pem  
Identity added: KeyPairFileName.pem (KeyPairFileName.pem)
```

Per previous SO solutions for connection time outs (and Java I/O errors) I stopped all processes (stop-all.sh) before taking further action. In some cases, simply start-all.sh (from bin/ or conf/) worked for people. Not in my case.

So, I tried a further recommendation in SO solutions and $ rm -Rf the hadoop /tmp/ that had been created before starting processes (did not work - same error), or formatting the namenode and starting processes (did not work - same error).

Per SO solutions involving hadoop-1.2.1 I checked the core-site.xml file to make sure that fs.default.name was correctly specified. Re-ran process start; but, same error.

Per other SO solutions, I upped the port number for core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml (from :8020 to :9050 and :8021 to :9051, respectively). Re-ran process start; but, same error.

Per another SO solution related to the hadoop tmp/ directory, I added two additional properties to the hdfs-site.xml (see environments, below). Re-ran process start; but, same error.

Per yet another SO solution, I checked port activity at 50070 and 22. There was no activity on either port.

I have stopped and terminated the EC2 instances, repeating the entire tutorial, but with the same results.

I am banging my head against the wall here, and would really like to know if

a) I missed a *hidden* step (the tutorials are sometimes hard to follow) that is leading to this failure, and/or

b) there is some additional step that needs to be taken, that if not taken, will lead to a failure to load and start the hadoop processes.

Thank-you in advance for you time and effort.

Richard Porter
MBA Student, USF (Sarasota-Manatee)

Using the public AMI for ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
Using hadoop-1.2.1
Using Java version 1.7.0_8

The .bashrc was modified to include:

```
export HADOOP_CONF=/home/ubuntu/hadoop/conf
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/hadoop

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

export PATH=$PATH"$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin
```

the hadoop tmp/ was created as hdfstmp in /home/ubuntu/ with owner:group ubuntu:ubuntu on the master only, per the tutorial.

The hadoop cluster configuration files (copied to NN, SNN and Slave, alike):

hadoop-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://<Master Public DNS>:9050</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/ubuntu/hdfstmp</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Because there is only one slave, the replication value = "1"

The hdfs-site.xml file was further modified to include:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/home/ubuntu/hdfstmp/dfs/name/data</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/home/ubuntu/hdfstmp/dfs/name</value>
</property>
```

mapred.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>hdfs://<Master Public DNS>:9051</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

The masters and slaves files for the NN, SNN, and Slave were modified to change them from "localhost" the appropriate URLs (or left blank).

**Notes** (I presently lack the ability to include more than 2 hyper-links, but am providing the searchable titles of on-line references).

[Note A]: Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux (Single-Node Cluster) by Michael Noll
  [Note B]: Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux (Multi-Node Cluster) by Michael Noll

Comment: I thought it might be helpful to add the following from the security group AWS console: <br>
Type // Protocol // Port Range // Source  <br>
All TCP // TCP // 0-65535 // Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0  <br>
All ICMP // ICMP // 0 - 65535 // Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0  <br>
SSH // TCP // 22 // Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Hey same problem here. Could you let me know how it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps
1. Install openssh-server and client in NameNode and DataNode
2. generate ssh-keygen by running below commands

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P “”

cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

3. Setup ssh connection between two nodes

   ssh namenode

   ssh datanode
4. Now try to run hadoop-daemons again

Comment: thank-you for the suggestion @Krishna. I will look into how to install openssh, then try your solution. I will let you know how it turns out.